# Why isn't my image fullscreen? xcode (sprite kit)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, image, sprite

```
-(void)AnimateBackground
{
//set our background animation
SKAction *Fadein = [SKAction fadeInWithDuration: 2];
SKAction *Fadeout = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:1.25];

SKAction *wait2 = [SKAction waitForDuration: 2];
SKAction *wait4 = [SKAction waitForDuration:4];

SKSpriteNode *background_2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background2"];

SKAction *sequence2 = [SKAction sequence:@[wait4, Fadein, wait2,Fadeout]];

background_2.position = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2);
background_2.alpha = 0;
background_2.size = CGSizeMake((float)screenHeight/2, (float)screenWidth/2);


[self addChild:background_2];
[background_2 runAction:sequence2];
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    //init several sizes used in all scene
    screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;


    [self AnimateBackground];


}
return self;
}
```

The image does not fill the entire screen.

http://gyazo.com/5dc5e4d7551475f1abac1189ba61bd09

There is a gyazo of the result. I don't think there is much else to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here, and I'm pretty sure they all occur in this line:

```
background_2.size = CGSizeMake((float)screenHeight/2, (float)screenWidth/2);
```

`CGSizeMake()` takes two arguments; width and height in that order, so your code should look like this:

```
background_2.size = CGSizeMake((float)screenWidth/2, (float)screenHeight/2);
```

Also, it is not clear to me why you are dividing both values by two. Try this:

```
background_2.size = CGSizeMake(screenWidth, screenHeight);
```